# How to set SQS batch size to 1 in Terraform?

Tags: terraform, amazon-sqs

We're using an SQS in AWS to trigger a specific support Lambda that we have. Everything works or so, but in this case I'd like to make sure the batch size is 1 on the SQS.

I've [read on this official terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/sqs_queue) doc and cannot find anything about the batch size. I've also read [this official AWS article on SQS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html) tips but they do mention batch sizes, but not how to change them.

Is there any way to set the batch size to, let's say 1? I know this can have consequences in terms of execution time and cost, but in this particular case that does not matter for us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is set on the [AWS Lambda event source mapping](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp%20%20/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_event_source_mapping), the thing that connects SQS and Lambda:

```
resource "aws_lambda_event_source_mapping" "example" {
  event_source_arn = aws_sqs_queue.sqs_queue_test.arn
  function_name    = aws_lambda_function.example.arn
  batch_size       = 1
}
```